# multiple transform animations in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, transform

I have a 2 part question:

1 . how can I animate in jQuery multiple transformation (such as scale() + rotate()) simultaneously on click?

(I've tried using the `step` function like this:

```
$("target").animate({'left':'100px',myScaleProperty: 2, myRotationPreperty: 180}, {step: function(now,tween) {
if (tween.prop == myScaleProperty) {
$(this).css({'transform','scale('+now+')'})
}
if (tween.prop == myRotationProperty){
$(this).css({'transform','rotate('+now+'deg)'})
}
},duration:'slow','linear'})
```

2 .  how can I make a reversible animation on jQuery (without defining another reverse animation function)?

Comment: You should look into Greensock. http://www.greensock.com/gsap-js/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've a blog post showing how to scale and rotate at the same time

http://bcksp.blogspot.com/2011/12/css3-based-animation-instead-of-jquery.html

here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/alsadi/sFzSR/

having such css you can use jquery to add the animation class or remove it

```
transform:rotate(180deg) scale(0.5);
```

in jquery javascript it might look like this

```
 $(this).css({transform:'rotate(180deg) scale(0.5)'})
```

UPDATE: replace infinite transition animation loop with single trigger-based transform

Comment: This works perfectly for a repetitive animation, but how do I apply multiple transformation on an element that is activated once per click (and stays in the final state of the animation indefinitely) until a different button is pressed to deactivate the animation (and reverse the animation to the initial state - question 2)?

Comment: I've added a last button on http://jsfiddle.net/alsadi/sFzSR/ which uses ```$(this).css({transform:'rotate(180deg) scale(0.5)'})```

Comment: Great! I think I got my answer. I appreciate the help!